# Single Responsibility Principle - Loading a list from a file?

Tags: oop, class-design, single-responsibility-principle

Say I have a Car class:

```
class Car 
{
  string GetMake()
  string GetModel()
  int GetYear()
}
```

And I have a custom CarService class that holds a list of cars:

```
class CarService
{
  void AddCar(Car car)
  void RemoveCar(Car car)
  List<Car> GetCars()
   ... other methods removed for clarity...
}
```

Now I want to load a list of cars from a file to the CarService class.  My old OOP instinct would be to put this as a method like LoadFromFile() on the CarService class.  However as I'm learning about SRP and testability now I'm not so sure.

Following the single responsibility principle, what is the correct way to design this?  Should I have a CarLoader class?

**UPDATE**

I think the solution should be the same in a wide variety of languages but I'll be using C++.  My question would be identical if I was using C#, Java, or python.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language you're going to implement this in, I'd say either a `load_carservice` function or an equivalent static method would suffice.

The static method solution might be said to violate the SRP, because the serialization format might change while the rest of the class stays the same. This is one of the reasons why I never program in languages that force me to put everything in a class. If your language forces you to do this, and you want to adhere by SRP strictly, then an extra class would be called for.

Comment: Well it's unlikely I'm going to use a static method because I'm learning those are evil from a testability point of view.  I don't necessarily want to adhere to SRP strictly, but if it's generally considered better design then I will probably go for an SRP solution.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should *not* have a `CarLoader` class. At least based on what you've shown, your `CarService` class doesn't look very useful either. At least right off, it *looks* like (if it does anything useful at all) your `CarService` is basically trying to build a `set` on top of a `List`. I think I'd write the code something like this:

```
class Car { 
// ...
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, std::Car &c) { 
        return is >> c.model >> c.year >> c.color;
    }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::Car const &c) {
       return os << c.model << "\t" << c.year << "\t" << c.color;
};

std::set<Car> cars;

std::ifstream car_file("cars.txt");

// read data from the file:
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Car>(car_file),
          std::istream_iterator<Car>(),
          std::inserter(cars));
```

`std::set` already knows how to add and remove items...

Comment: Sorry yes CarService does have other functionality that I'm leaving out to simplify.  Your solution is clever and nicely leverages the C++ language.  It's likely my CarService class could be refactored to be better, however I'm more concerned about the general case of loading an object from a file under the SRP paradigm.  In your example, what if there were two different file types I wanted to load from?

Comment: @User: it depends. How do they differ (and why?) Depending on the situation, it can be useful to use a proxy class to provide conversions from different sources, but it's hard to give very specific suggestions to such a general question.